# How do I use "centeroncell" on a cell name with an apostrophe in it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind, the-elder-scrolls-series

For example I typed player->coc "caius cosades' house" but that hasn't worked at all.  Tried replacing the apostrophe with a dash, underscore, and deleting it entirely but still doesn't work.

Comment: [According to this](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Caius_Cosades%27_House), the apostrophe comes after "Cosades", not "Caius". I don’t know anything about it, but there it says the location ID would be `Balmora, Caius Cosades' House`. Maybe this is what you have to type?

Comment: Pardon my typo, I corrected it in the in OP.  But I did use the right spelling in the console and it still didn't work.  (Sorry for the late reply!)

Answer (score 2):

The correct location ID for the example is "Balmora, Caius Cosades' House"

So, just type this:

```
coc "Balmora, Caius Cosades' House"
```

It should work, worked for me anyway.

[image: console screenshot]

Usually the houses in cities go like this:

```
"CityName, Firstname Surname's House"
```

Sometimes the House can be Manor or something else. Also, you don't need to add the "player->" when using the COC (or TCL, fixme.. etc.) command.

Hopefully this helped.